# Unable to retrieve username and password using Sessions

Tags: android, session

In my Android project I have 3 classes:

> 1st a List class contains a login button and 2 EditText boxes for user name and password respectively

Code looks like this :

```
      signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {               
        public void onClick(View v)
        {  
        EditText etxt_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usereditlog);  
        t_id = etxt_user.getText().toString();             
        EditText etxt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwdeditlog);   
        password = etxt_password.getText().toString();  

        }           
    })
```

> 2nd class is App which extends Application

```
             class App extends Application 
          {
                 List session = new List();

              public String getUsername() 
              {
                    return session.t_id;
              }

           public void setUsername(String username) 
             {
                  session.t_id = username;
             }

           public String getPassword() 
              {
                  return session.password;
              }

           public void setPassword(String password) 
              {
                 session.password = password;
              }


            }
```

> 3rd class is Utils where in I am facing problem in retrieving the user name and password entered during the initial execution of the List class

```
    public class Utils extends Activity 
  {
public static List mySessionObject = null;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utils.mySessionObject = new List();
               //some extra initalization, for example setting userId
                  App app = (App) getApplication();
                 String username = app.getUsername();
                 String password=  app.getPassword();
            }
        });

     }
    }
```

The problem I am facing is retrieving the username and password from my 3rd class. For some reason it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name of your application class in manifest file like as below

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="App" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

and initializing variable like below....

```
((App)getApplication()).setUsername(name);
```

and retrive using following line,

```
String name= ((App)getApplication()).getUsername();
```

Comment: As per my code, for initialization I should write ((App)getApplication()).setUsername(username) right?

Comment: "username" you specified within the parenthesis is the value need to pass.. you need initialize it locally on same class... or else try this sample ((App)getApplication()).setUsername("test");

Comment: any changes in the List class? Can I create a button in Utils class and  set a Listener that on click of the button display username and password as toast message just to confirm it is working ?

Comment: no need to create the object for App class... you simply retrieve the value using this String name= ((App)getApplication()).getUsername();

Comment: for that you need to register the App class name in manifest file

Comment: ok so that can be done from another class right ? I can retreive username and password from any other class also right provided i have registered the class name in manifest file>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5192/discussion-between-parth-90-and-karthi-heno)

Comment: hey @Karthi_heno I am getting ClassCastException ..what to do ?